# MiNiFi - How to get processors list and number of queued flowfiles?

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I'd like to monitor state of the running MiNiFi flow, especially get list of the processors and number of queued flowfiles for each processor. I'm trying to use [FlowStatus Script Query](https://nifi.apache.org/minifi/system-admin-guide.html), eg.:

```sh
$ ./minifi.sh flowStatus systemdiagnostics:processorstats
{"controllerServiceStatusList":null,"processorStatusList":null,"connectionStatusList":null,"remoteProcessGroupStatusList":null,"instanceStatus":null,"systemDiagnosticsStatus":{"garbageCollectionStatusList":null,"heapStatus":null,"contentRepositoryUsageList":null,"flowfileRepositoryUsage":null,"processorStatus":{"loadAverage":1.99,"availableProcessors":2}},"reportingTaskStatusList":null,"errorsGeneratingReport":[]}

$ ./minifi.sh flowStatus processor:all:health,stats,bulletins
{"controllerServiceStatusList":null,"processorStatusList":[],"connectionStatusList":null,"remoteProcessGroupStatusList":null,"instanceStatus":null,"systemDiagnosticsStatus":null,"reportingTaskStatusList":null,"errorsGeneratingReport":[]}

$ /minifi.sh flowStatus processor:MyProcessorName:health,stats,bulletins
{"controllerServiceStatusList":null,"processorStatusList":[],"connectionStatusList":null,"remoteProcessGroupStatusList":null,"instanceStatus":null,"systemDiagnosticsStatus":null,"reportingTaskStatusList":null,"errorsGeneratingReport":["Unable to get status for request 'processor:MyProcessorName:health,stats,bulletins' due to:org.apache.nifi.minifi.status.StatusRequestException: No processor with key MyProcessorName to report status on"]}
```

but I'm receiving only nulls. What should I do to be able retrieve data which I want (enable some option in config?)? Is it possible using flowStatus queries? My flow which is running contains several processors, so why `systemdiagnostics` shows only two `availableProcessors` and why I can't use `flowStatus processor` command to get any processor data?

Unfortunately NiFi/MiNiFi documentation is very poor, so I'm not even sure if I can retrieve processors data (number of queued elements and processors list) in this way. If not, maybe do you know some other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any processors in a flow running on this instance of MiNiFi? Each response from the queries you've submitted show no processors. In fact, the third example says this explicitly -- `"Unable to get status for request 'processor:MyProcessorName:health,stats,bulletins' due to:org.apache.nifi.minifi.status.StatusRequestException: No processor with key MyProcessorName to report status on"`.

Comment: Yes, my config.yml contains one Process Group and several processors as its children. The flow is running and working (I can receive correct HTTP response from `HandleHttpResponse` processor)

Comment: am I right that MiNiFi doesn't provide REST API like NiFi (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html)? Querying interface is the only way of getting information about the flow?